# How to check an OPTIONAL_COMPONENT using find_package in cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, module, qt5, find-package

I want to build a specific feature of a GUI only if a certain component of a package is found. If not, the GUI should be built either way, but without this feature. The idea would be something like this, but I don't know the correct notation (or even if it is possible at all) to check the component itself:

```
find_package(Qt5 QUIET COMPONENTS Core Widgets OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS Charts)

if (Qt5_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Gui enabled")
    ...
    if (Charts_FOUND) // This is the check I want to make
        message(STATUS "Optional feature enabled")
        ...
    else()
        message(STATUS "QtCharts not found")
    endif()
...
```

In cmake documentation: [Finding Packages](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Finding%20Packages.html), in the **Built-In Find Modules** it says..

**<XX>_<YY>_FOUND**
If false, then the optional <YY> part of <XX> package is unavailable.

So I tried `if(Qt5_Charts_FOUND)` , but still, QtCharts is not found.

I am sure QtCharts is installed and working.

Comment: My guess is `Charts` was not found. What happens if you remove `OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS` so that `Charts` is a required component?

Comment: If I remove OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS: 
"Gui enabled"
"QtCharts not found"

So, QtCharts is found by find_package, otherwise it would return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way of determine whether a component is found **depends on the package**.

"Built-In Find Modules" referred by the CMake tutorial are those Find modules which are shipped with CMake itself. They are documented here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-modules.7.html#find-modules.
As you could find, this list doesn't contain `FindQt5` module.

Since Qt5 [defines](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-get-started.html#imported-library-targets) IMPORTED target `Qt5::<component>` for every component which is found, one could assume that such target won't be defined for an optional component which is missed:

```
find_package(Qt5 QUIET COMPONENTS Core Widgets OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS Charts)
if (Qt5_FOUND)
    # Qt5 has been found, will all required components
    if(TARGET Qt5::Charts)
       # Charts component has been found
    else()
       # Charts component hasn't been found
    endif()
endif()
```

---

If a package is searched by a Find script, and that script uses [find_package_handle_standard_args](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.html#command:find_package_handle_standard_args) helper, then given helper processes "optionality" of components by treating the variable `<PackageName>_<Component>_FOUND` as indicator of whether component is found.

If a package is searched by a Config script, then given script should process "optionality" of components by checking variables `<PackageName>_FIND_REQUIRED_<Component>`. E.g. the script [QtConfig.cmake](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/f99e5183274f01774d8b50024b0cd030a03c804f/cmake/QtConfig.cmake.in#L180) performs such checks. Not all Config scripts check that variables. A scripts which doesn't check that variables treats (incorrectly) optional components as required ones.